# Downloading dynamically created canvas is blank

Tags: javascript, html, svg, canvas

I have trouble downloading a dynamically created canvas. I want the user to be able to create an SVG image and download it as a bitmap. To achieve this, I create a canvas and draw my SVG image onto it. Then I want to download it. However, the canvas is blank. Now I know that this is probably because the canvas has not yet fully loaded, but attaching an `onload` listener on `canvas` didn't work as it never fired.

Clicking the link a second time downloads the correct image, another hint to me that it's a timing issue. Can someone tell me why the `onload` is never fired? Maybe I'm misunderstanding how the event is handled or what causes it.

```js
document.getElementById('downloadDirectly').addEventListener('click', function () {
    downloadDirectly();
});

document.getElementById('downloadOnLoad').addEventListener('click', function () {
    downloadOnLoad();
});

function createCanvas() {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = 'data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1000" height="1000"><line x1="0" y1="0" x2="500" y2="500" stroke="black" stroke-width="5"/></svg>';

    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = 1000;
    canvas.height = 1000;
    canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(img, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000);
    return canvas;
}

function downloadDirectly() {
    let canvas = {};
    canvas = createCanvas();
    let el = document.getElementById('downloadDirectly');
    el.href = canvas.toDataURL();
    console.log('This downloads, but canvas is not ready');
    el.download = name + ".png";
}

function downloadOnLoad() {
    let canvas = {};
    canvas = createCanvas();
    canvas.onload = function() {
        console.log('This is never reached :(');
        let el = document.getElementById('downloadOnLoad');
        el.href = canvas.toDataURL();
        el.download = name + ".png";
    };
}
```

```html
<p><a id="downloadDirectly">Download directly</a></p>
<p><a id="downloadOnLoad">Download using onLoad</a></p>
```

Comment: canvas does not have an `onLoad` method. What are you loading? this doesn't make sense...

Comment: One thing to note is that, you should be calling createCanvas() when the page is loaded, not when the downloads are needed.

Comment: `createCanvas()` sets `img.src` and then _immediately_ draws it to the canvas. You need to wait for `img.onload` before you can pass it to `drawImage()`.

Comment: According to [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_canvas.asp), a canvas _"supports the standard properties and events."_ which include the load event.

Comment: @J.Doe no it does not...

Comment: @J. Doe This does not include the load event, the canvas tag does not have a src attribute and thus does not have load functionality

Comment: @PatrickRoberts that was it, I thought the canvas was not ready yet when it was in fact the image, thank you. Regarding the onload on canas, maybe I misunderstood the explanation on the site. It said that _"The canvas object also supports the standard properties and events."_, and under _events_ was also the `load` event.

Comment: Basically, don't use w3schools as a reliable source of documentation. It has many technical errors, and while it is better than it used to be, it is still not as trustworthy as sources like [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript).

Comment: Just to be clear, HTMLCanvasElement, just like any other object inheriting from HTMLElement does have the `onload` [global attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes#attr-onload), w3school was not wrong here. Now, this doesn't mean that they will be able to fire a load event, there is nothing in the current specs that could lead to such an event. cc@PatrickRoberts